# Converting very large decimal numbers to hexadecimal (1.67119535743*10^33)

Tags: c#, php, decimal, hex

I'm curious as to if it'd be possible to convert a very, very large decimal number such as 1.67119535743*10^33/1.67119535743E+33 to hexadecimal via PHP or C#. All my previous attempts have failed, unfortunately. Thanks to all in advance!

Comment: Did any of the comments in the http://php.net/dechex documentation help? I see a number of implementations.

Comment: If you need to do it by hand then use the "Any Base Caclulator" on the Google Play Market: http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ewe.radixcalculator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean, convert it to a hex string?  You might look at bigint libraries, like [this one on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/biginteger.aspx).

```
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger("12345678901234567890");
string s = bi.ToHexString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you're storing the number as a byte array, and want to output the hex number as a string?

This should do the job in C#:

```
public static string ConvertToHex(byte[] value)
{
    var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < sb.Length; i++)
        sb.Append(value[i].ToString("X"));

    return sb.ToString();
}
```